# Azure Kubernetes Service: How to move the pods from the Spot node pool to Regular node pool after the Spot node pool is evicted?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I have total **3** node pools are as follow:

1. **database pool** - regular node pool
2. **content pool** - regular node pool
3. **content spot pool** - spot node pool

Initially, **content pool** have **0 node** count with enabled autoscaler.
I have deployed one nginx pod deployment on the **content spot pool**. which has minimum node count 1 and maximum node count 3.
The deployment file for nginx are as follow:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 2
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: agentpool
                operator: In
                values:
                - contentspotpool
          - weight: 1
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: agentpool
                operator: In
                values:
                - contentpool
```

When the content spot pool is evicted I want that the pod on the **content spot pool** are to be shifted on **content pool**. But, the pod are scheduled on the **database pool**..!

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?..

Also How can I setup a **database pool** in such way that it refuses all the new pods?

AKS version used - 1.18.14

Answer (score 1):

I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer as there was a similar answer but was deleted by its author.

In this case, you can use [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/):

> Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. One or more taints are applied to a node; this marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints.

You may add a `taint` to nodes from the **database pool** and specify a `toleration` that "matches" this `taint` only for Pods that can be scheduled on the **database pool**.

---

I've created a simple example to illustrate how it may work.

I have only one worker node and I added a specific `taint` to this node:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS   ROLES    AGE     
database-pool       Ready    <none>   6m9s  

$ kubectl taint nodes database-pool type=database:NoSchedule
node/database-pool tainted

$ kubectl describe node database-pool | grep -i taint
Taints:             type=database:NoSchedule
```

Only `Pods` with the following `toleration` will be allowed to be scheduled onto the `database-pool` node:

```
tolerations:
- key: "type"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "database"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

I created two `Pods`: `web` (does not tolerate the `taint`) and `web-with-toleration` (tolerates the `taint`):

```
$ cat web.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: web
  name: web
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: web
    
$ cat web-with-toleration.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: web
  name: web-with-toleration
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: web
  tolerations:
  - key: "type"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "database"
    effect: "NoSchedule"

$ kubectl apply -f web.yml
pod/web created
$ kubectl apply -f web-with-toleration.yml
pod/web-with-toleration created
```

Finally, we can check which `Pod` has been correctly scheduled:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE                                         
web                   0/1     Pending   0          6m13s   <none>       <none>                                       
web-with-toleration   1/1     Running   0          6m8s    10.76.0.14   database-pool
```

It is possible to use [*Node affinity*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) and *Taints* at the same time to have a great control over the placement of `Pods` on specific nodes.

> Node affinity, is a property of Pods that attracts them to a set of nodes (either as a preference or a hard requirement).
> Taints are the opposite -- they allow a node to repel a set of pods.